# Getting sheet names using VB from macros enabled workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on getting the names of the  worksheets in the sheet tab from a macros enabled workbook. Such as the Home, Builder. Image shown below:

[image]

When researching through the internet, all I see is the following code, which give me all the worksheets names.

```
objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(File_location.Text)

For Each Me.objWorkSheets In objWorkBook.Worksheets
          workbook_worksheets.Items.Add(objWorkSheets.Name)
  End If
Next
```

When Alt + F11 is clicked, the macros section is opened up. The circled section in the image are additional worksheets which are not seen in the first image, but some are hidden and visible.

[image]

Is there a way to only get sheet names which are shown in the first image, without using the filter option such as visible or hidden.

Thank you

Comment: When you say "to only get sheet names", do you mean to only get names for sheets which are visible?

Comment: I have edited my post above to improve my explanation. Please see above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without using the filter option such as visible"?  The normal way would be to include `If objWorksheets.Visible` within the loop

Comment: I used that code and it work fine, but this showed the name of sheets such as: Import, RMs.. Apart from get all the name and removing these ones is it possible to get only the Home, Builder, parameters and Lab Test names. Is there another function other than visible and hidden.  I just want to know if it's possible. Thank you